# Как реализовать удаление сообщений через определенное время? Aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Хочу реализовать удаление сообщения через n секунд в боте на aiogram.
Как это можно сделать?
Я знаю про то что есть метод в `asyncio` - `asyncio.sleep(1)`.
Но есть ли другие методы?
Например чтобы после выдачи результата, после ввода команды через какое-то время удалялся результат, чтобы не засорять чат.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='test')
async def test (message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Test') #и например что то по типу delete_message=10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из немного костыльного, могу предложить вот такой.

```
import asyncio

@dp.message_handler(commands='test')
async def test(message: types.Message):
    new_msg = await message.answer('Test')
    # делайем слип (асинхронно)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    # на всякий случай проверяем есть ли еще сообщение
    try:
        await new_msg.delete()
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Ибо внутреннего способа я не знаю.

Comment: И на том благодарен.